# How to do update rows in SQLite table using SQLite3 and Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

I am new to python and I don't really understand the sql thing that well. Currently on the 6th week of team treehouse so please bare with me here if these are noob questions.

**Goal**

1. Import CSV with stock_tickers and 5 other columns of data
2. Convert CSV into pandas dataframe
3. Import dataframe into database. If there is already the unique stock_ticker for it to not add a new row, but next to check if the data in the other 5 columns is different. If it is than update it.

Right now I can do steps #1 and #2 and half of #3. With the help on here was able to get the looping thing to work. If there is a new stock_ticker row in the csv it will add it to database. If the data changes for an existing stock_ticker it won't do any updates.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        df[df.index == i].to_sql(name='stocks', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
        conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        pass
```

**Current Code looks like this**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import csv
import sqlite3

### IMPORT CSV ###
stock_csv_file = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\code_projects\FIRE_Dashboard\db\alpha_vantage_active_stocks.csv')

### CHANGING INDEX NAMES FROM CSV TO TABLE NAMES ###
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_csv_file)
df = df.rename(columns = {"symbol":"stock_ticker", "name":"stock_name", "exchange":"stock_exchange", "ipoDate":"stock_ipoDate", "delistingDate":"stock_delistingDate", "status":"stock_status"})

### UPDATING DATABSE WITH SQLITE3###
conn = sqlite3.connect('stockmarket.db')
c = conn.cursor()

insert_statement = """
INSERT INTO stocks (stock_ticker,
                    stock_name,
                    stock_exchange,
                    stock_ipoDate,
                    stock_delistingDate,
                    stock_status
                    )
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT (stock_ticker) DO UPDATE
    SET (stock_status)"""
    

for i in range(len(df)):
    values = tuple(df.iloc[i])
    c.execute(insert_statement, values)
```

The error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_stock_tickers.py", line 71, in <module>
    c.execute(insert_statement, values)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Found these posts that talk about it, but still getting lost >.<

- [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)
- [python Datetime and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904642/python-datetime-and-sqlite)
- [Loop through individual rows and update those rows SQLite3 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850317/loop-through-individual-rows-and-update-those-rows-sqlite3-python)

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Code after solution**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import csv
import sqlite3

### IMPORT CSV ###
stock_csv_file = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\code_projects\FIRE_Dashboard\db\alpha_vantage_active_stocks.csv')

### CHANGING INDEX NAMES FROM CSV TO TABLE NAMES ###
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_csv_file)
df = df.rename(columns = {"symbol":"stock_ticker", "name":"stock_name", "exchange":"stock_exchange", "ipoDate":"stock_ipoDate", "delistingDate":"stock_delistingDate", "status":"stock_status"})

### UPDATING DATABSE WITH SQLITE3###
conn = sqlite3.connect('stockmarket.db')
c = conn.cursor()

insert_statement = """
INSERT INTO stocks (stock_ticker,
                    stock_name,
                    stock_exchange,
                    stock_ipoDate,
                    stock_delistingDate,
                    stock_status
                    )
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT (stock_ticker) DO UPDATE
    SET stock_status = EXCLUDED.stock_status"""
    

for i in range(len(df)):
    values = tuple(df.iloc[i])
    c.execute(insert_statement, values)
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `ON CONFLICT` clause of your query:

```
ON CONFLICT (stock_ticker) DO UPDATE
    SET (stock_status)
```

This is not valid SQLite syntax. If you want to update `stock_status` when another row already exists with the same `stock_ticker`, you can use pseudo-table `EXCLUDED` like so:

```
INSERT INTO stocks (stock_ticker,
                    stock_name,
                    stock_exchange,
                    stock_ipoDate,
                    stock_delistingDate,
                    stock_status
                    )
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT (stock_ticker) DO UPDATE
    SET stock_status = EXCLUDED.status
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That solved the issue :)